# Dispatch Toggle in Redux without saving it in State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

**How I do it right now**

I have a list of items. Right now, when the user presses button X, `shouldShowItem` is toggled. `shouldShowItem` ultimately lies in redux and is passed down into `Item` as a prop. it's either `true` or `false`. When it changes, toggleDisplay is called and changes state in my hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  toggleDisplay(!display); //this is just a useState hook call
}, [shouldShowItem]); //PS: I'm aware that I don't need this extra step here, but my actual code is a bit more complicated, so I just simplified it here.
```

My Problem is, that I have one single `shouldShowItem` property in redux, not one `shouldShowItem` *for each* item. I don't want to move this property into the redux-state for each and every item.

**Problem:**

The problem with my construction however is that `shouldShowItem` is being saved, which means that if I toggle it at *time X* for *item Y*, and then my *Item Z* also re-renders as a result of an unrelated event, it will re-render with an updated `shouldShowItem` state, - although that state change was intended for *Item X*.

Essentially, I am saving the state of `shouldShowItem` in redux **while** I just need a toggle, that I can dispatch once, that works on the current Item, and then isn't read / needed anymore. I want to basically dispatch a toggle, - I don't care about the state of each item within redux, I just care that it's toggled once.

Suggestions?

**Edit: More Code**

Item:

```
const Item = ({shouldShowItem, itemText, updateCurrentItem})=>
{
    const [display, toggleDisplay] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isSelected) {
        toggleDisplay(!display);
      }
    }, [shouldShowItem]);

    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          toggleDisplay(!display);
          updateCurrentItem(item._id);
        }}
      >
       {display && <span>{itemText}</span>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Mapping through item list:

```
  allItems.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <Item
            key={i}
            shouldShowItem={this.props.shouldShowItem}
            itemText={item.text}
            updateCurrentItem={this.props.updateCurrentItem}
        );
      });
```

The props here come from redux, so `shouldShowItem` is a boolean value that lies in redux, and `updateCurrentItem` is an action creator. And well, in redux i simply just toggle the `shouldShowItem` true & false whenever the toggle action is dispatched. (The toggle action that sets & unsets true/false of `shouldShowItem` is in some other component and works fine)

Comment: You could instead put a property in your redux store called `activeItems` - an array of IDs relating to the items you have toggled

Comment: Thanks! I could do that, but I feel like I really don't need to save this at all. I'd just like to have a toggle without the need to save any state. :/ It might also be an anti-pattern, I'm not sure, but for my use case it seems really neat right now.

Comment: you need to show more code: list, where this button lies, what its supposed to do etc..

Comment: @Lelouch Updated my question. Where the button lies is not important, I believe, it simply calls an action creator that toggles `shouldShowItem` true/false. I'd like to implement an action creator that tells my Item Component: "Hey, update now!" but doesnt need to save the state then afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a boolean `shouldShowItem`, why not convert it into an object of ids with boolean values:

```js
const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState({id_1: false, id_2: false})

const toggleDisplay = id => {
  setShowItem({...showItem, [id]: !showItem[id]})
  updateCurrentItem(id)
}

allItems.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <Item
      key={i}
      shouldShowItem={showItem[item._id]}
      itemText={item.text}
      updateCurrentItem={toggleDisplay}
  );
});
```

```js
const Item = ({shouldShowItem, itemText, updateCurrentItem}) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => toggleDisplay(item._id)}
    >
     {shouldShowItem && <span>{itemText}</span>}
    </div>
  )
}
```